# Does hash code is being stored in SyncBlockIndex/SyncBlock

Tags: c#, .net, gethashcode

Every object in .net has headers (`SyncBlockIndex` and `MethodTablePointer`), and when you call `GetHashCode()` the result could be saved in `SyncBlockIndex` if there is no *linked* SyncBlock to this object, or in SyncBlock if so.

When we don't override `GetHashCode` method hash code is the save during object existence, but how hash code will be storing in case we return dynamic hash code (dependent on object's state)?

I know that hash code should be the same during object existence, the purpose of question is to understand how hash code is being stored in SyncBlockIndex or in SyncBlock.

Comment: If you are writing code that has a dynamic hash code be sure to read the "[Notes to Inheritors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx#Inheritors)" on the MSDN *"In general, for mutable reference types, you should override GetHashCode only if: 
•You can compute the hash code from fields that are not mutable; or 
• **You can ensure that the hash code of a mutable object does not change while the object is contained in a collection that relies on its hash code.** "*

Comment: It is very heavily micro-optimized.  Yes, it can store the hash code.  It can also store the lock owner and recursion count when you use it in the *lock* statement.  Can't do both, if you ask it to do both then it assumes the third role, a syncblock index.  Never do both, that's pretty crazy.  But supported.

Comment: Hans, what do you mean "never do both"? And, syncblock index can store generated hash code (with not overridden method) and some more information, or can have a pointer to SyncTableEntry if there are too much information that could be stored in syncblock index (then SyncTableEntry stores hash code and more information), am I right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how hash code will be storing in case we return dynamic hash code (dependent on object's state)?

If the hash code is dynamically computed via an override of `GetHashCode` is is not stored anywhere...

The usage of `SyncBlockIndex` as the "default" hash code for an object is an implementation detail and should not be relied upon for anything outside of the framework.